# Spring Calculating Positive Results at Post Codes

Tags: java, html, spring

I am trying to make a table with a list of post codes and how many positive cases there are that post code.
[image]

The picture below is what I have currently got, although the final post code "LE1 7XB" should have 2 since it has 2 positive cases. How do I do this the code is below is what I have written so far.

```
<table style="width:50%">
<tr>
<th scope="col">Post Code ('s)</th>
<th scope="col">No. Of Infections</th>
</tr>
<c:set var="count" value="0"/>
<c:forEach items="${PostCodes}" var="POST">
<!-- CHECK IF USER IS POSITIVE -->
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="result" varStatus="myIndex">
<c:set var="neg" value="Positive"/>
<c:set var="val"  value="${result.testResult}"/>
<!-- Checks strings to see if they same -->
<c:if test="${neg eq val}">
<!-- LOOP TO CHECK IF A POSITIVE USERS POST CODE IS IN ARRAY -->
<c:set var="currentPost" value="${PostCodes[count]}"/>
<c:set var="userPost" value="${result.postCode }"/>
<!-- Check if users post code is in array of positive post codes -->
<c:if test="${currentPost eq userPost}">
<c:set var="Count" value="${count + 1 }"/>
</c:if>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
<tr>
<!-- PRINTS ALL POST CODES AND NUMBER OF POSITIVE CASES -->
<th>${POST}</th>
<td>${Count }</td>
```

Comment: `Count` and `count` variables are different

Answer (score 0):

In the loops variable `count` always `0`, you don't increment it. You just set variable `Count`. I think it's the same by code logics, but variables are different.